# How to use constant data as variables instead of defining tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlperformance

I use MySql and PHP. To reduce the number of joins, I want to use constant data as variables instead of defining tables.

For example, I have a table named "province" that has columns 'province_name' and 'province_id' that I use province_id in other tables as foreign-key. But I want to know is it better that I define an array named province and use it, instead of joining tables to province table?

When I want to get a user's info, if I use province as a table, I should join user table to province table, but if I use province as an array, it isn't nessecery. I could write in my code: `$province[$user_province_id]`

Comment: Could you please add what you did so far.

Comment: It really depends on the size of the table and what you might need province for. If you know that 'province' table will only have for example a small amount of entries and it will be constant i.e. the table will not change, then it is better to use a constant associative array that will link province_id and province_name and then whenever you need it just call the array like your example '$province[$user_province_id]'.
If, on the other hand, you know that 'province' table might get more and more entries and it's size will change, then it is better to use a table.

Comment: @Filip My question is about the tables that will not change. I got the answer. Thank you so much Flip :)